# How to access return class values in another function python

Tags: python-2.7, class, oop

i have a class

```
class Sums():
    #someCode
    return result
```

If i import the class into another file and i want to use the value of the returned "result". How do i access this object?

Also, if i have the some Sums class

```
class Sums():
    def percent():
        #someCode
        #return Result
    def overall():
        # To be able to use the value of Result in the prior code
        # i try to access this object by using an object of sums
        # a = Sums()
        # result  = a.percent()
```

I am trying to understand oop in py and i am having difficulty on how to use and reference objects already created.

In functions of that same class, and when they are imported , how to use the return value of a class function to hold some information necessary to the program
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing classes and methods. Classes hold pieces of information, but do not run any code.  They can, however, contain methods, which have code that runs.  These methods can return a value, but the class cannot.

Try [reading through this tutorial](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/object_oriented_programming.html) and see if it makes more sense.  Good luck!

Comment: But if i do create methods in the classes, how do i access the return values?  or i cant? To use them in subsequent roles. example from the link you gave

Comment: class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 0

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

>>> a = BankAccount()
>>> b = BankAccount()
>>> a.deposit(100)
100

Comment: suppose i wanted to use the value of self.balance  that is returned in some code below. How do i do that? Sorry about the multiple commenting, i am unfamiliar with the platform.

Comment: I just put together an example for you.  Go here and press run: https://repl.it/E2RO/1 .  Hope it helps!